# XAML class does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, xaml

I get an error saying that the News class does not exist in the namespace.

Tried many solutions offered online such as rebuilding etc but nothing seems to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The page

```
<Page
    x:Class="KS2Buddy.Home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:KS2Buddy"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:data="using:KS2Buddy">
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:News"
                      x:Key="NewsItemTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

</Page>
```

The class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KS2Buddy
{
    class News
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to make it public?

Comment: I've tried that, still the same error.

Comment: Specify the type of Project (UWP or ...) . It looks non-repro.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using WPF, try replacing

```
xmlns:data="using:KS2Buddy"
```

by

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:KS2Buddy"
```

This answer is not targeted at UWP.

Comment: Probably right, the "using:..." syntax is supported in UWP, not regular WPF. Also make the class public.

Comment: I just realized, the WPF tag was edited by someone else, so it's quite possible the original question is about UWP... only the author can clarify.

Comment: Right, the x:DataType makes it UWP I think. Removed the WPF tag.